# compressing(zip) files in microsoft visual c++ express 2010

Tags: c++

I am supposed to compress my 9 solutions, but cannot find where I must click to do this.  I need to submit it on a homework website, and the professor says you must right click on the solution file and click compress to.  However, I cannot find this at all. Help

Answer (score 2):

Don't right click on the solution file, right click on the solution **folder** (in Windows explorer)

Send to -> Compressed (zipped) folder.

Comment: How do I exactly do that? Sorry, I am confused with what you mean on windows explorer?

Comment: @D.Zuber Hit WindowsKey+E, that is windows explorer.

Comment: Press the Windows key on your keyboard (at the bottom between Ctrl and Alt on mine) and the letter e at the same tme. This will open up Explorer. It's what you use to browse folders and files etc.

Answer (score 0):

(In right click menu of any file or folder in windows explorer)

[image]

You probably want to compress the whole directory as just sending the solution file won't do much good without the additional source code files and other misc files.